# Type classes with laws that contain not equalities/symmetries but inequalities/asymmetries

Tags: haskell, theory, typeclass, category-theory

All of the type classes that I've come across, I think have had laws that establish symmetries by specifying equations. I was wondering though if there are any prominent theoretical or even practical examples of type classes that establish asymmetries, i.e. ones that demand the lack of symmetry? By e.g. specifying `<expr1> /= <expr2>` or `<`,  or `not somePredicate(a, b)`.

I understand that inequality can be expressed as an equality with a free variable, i.e. `a > b` = `a + k = b` etc, but I'm thinking the introduction of free variables itself might align with my idea of enforced asymmetry.

What would be the (theoretical) applications of such law? And are there any (runnable) examples of this?

Alternatively: if this can't be considered Haskell enough to be on SO, should this go on [CS](http://cs.stackexchange.com) or [CSTheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: "I understand that inequality can be expressed as an equality with a free variable, i.e. `a > b = a + k = b`" Generally it can't. Even in this case it only works if your domain is specifically positive numbers.

Comment: how about `|a + k| = |b|` then or `a + k = b || a - k = b`. but in any case, does that aspect significantly affect the point in my question? (sincere question)

Comment: Still doesn't work, as `k` may be 0. For the question itself, I can just say that I haven't seen any examples of it.

Comment: Ah good point. Also, appreciate the "proto" answer. Still curious though, from a theoretical point of view, but I guess cs or cstheory then later on possibly...

Comment: If it ain't category theory, the tag seems inappropriate.

Comment: It sounds like you probably mean "inequations" rather than "inequalities". There are definitely cases where type class laws involving *inequalities* are useful, where a class method is required to be at least as defined as the given default.

Comment: A category theory expert is quite likely to be able to answer this or prove it's nonsensical. I've removed the remark.

Answer (score 1):

Algebraic laws in general typically are only specified in terms of equational identities, and not not disequalities. The standpoint to think about this is model theory. A *theory* can be thought of as 1) a collection of symbols, of different arities, so that sentences can be constructed from them (i.e. of arity 0 we might have sequences of numerals, of arity 1 we have negation, and of arity two we have addition) and 2) a set of equations that provide relations between sentences constructed from such signatures.

This lets us describe things like various arithmetic theories, groups, rings, modules, etc.

Now a *model* of a theory is a set of concrete assignments of mathematical objects (numbers, functions, etc) to the elements of the signature, such that the translation of sentences into the elements of the model respects these equations.

Categorically, we often think of a theory as a special sort of category of all possible sentences generated by the signature. The arrows in this category are implication -- sentences which may be generated from others by application of the equational identities. This in turn induces equivalences between all sentences which are the same under the application of the equational identities (this yields the "generators and relations" approach). And in turn, a model is simply a functor from this theory to any other category, though typically `Set`.

This yields a very nice adjunction between syntax and semantics. The greater the collection of sentences you want to model, the fewer the models you can get, and the more models you have, the smaller the set of sentences that will be satisfied by all of them. (Here I am only sketching the idea rather than filling in lots of important details).

In any case, one consequence of this that people tend to ignore, but that really pays off, is that in such a setting you want a "terminal model" that is the least among all models, just as you want an "initial theory" that admits all models. The terminal (aka trivial) model is the functor that sends everything in the theory to the empty set and maps on the empty set. Lots of very nice properties emerge when you have such things. But note -- to have such things, you must only have equational identities and not "disidentities." Such theories are called [Algebraic Theories.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_theory)

What does this all have to do with Haskell? Well, we can think of the signatures of typeclasses exactly as signatures of algebraic theories, and the laws of them as the equations of such theories. And that's generally how typeclasses are used in Haskell and why they were introduced -- to suit these sorts of situations.

But of course we don't *have* to do this -- we can have whatever laws we want. But we lose all sorts of nice properties along the way -- and often in fact find that disequalities mean our theory will have very few models, and with weird structure relating them. Since typeclasses are intended to capture *common* structure between various things, and since non-algebraic theories tend to fix unique(ish) models, then it turns out it is rarely the case that we would want to use disequality relations in typeclass laws. And indeed I can't think of any examples where I've seen it come up.

Here's another way to think of it -- consider a theory with equalities and disequalities both, and then eliminate the disequalities. What remains still admits all the prior models, but also may have a bunch of "unintended" ones. So we don't gain additional reasoning in terms of rewrites -- we just have certain models that are a priori excluded. Furthermore, when one wishes to rule out "unintended" models this is usually because we want to fix a particular "intended" one. And if we want to fix a particular intended model, the question immediately arises -- why not just use that concrete structure, instead of the more general typeclass?